# Oracle Join 3 tables - need all results

Tags: sql, oracle, join

- I need to show all records in test1 - this is the master table
- I need to show records in test2
- I need to show records in test3
- Final query =  need to show output of all 3 tables joined...
- test2 and test 3 may or may not match
- test1 will have all records.

as example

```
select * from test1 where ID = '8675309';  = 1 entry 
select * from test2 where ID = '8675309'; = null
select * from test3 where ID = '8675309'; = 1 entry
```

I have tried this approach however it is not working as expected.

```
   SELECT
    t1.id
FROM
    test1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
    AND
        t1.id = '8675309'
```

Results are not showing 8675309, there are showing all table values.

Comment: change the word AND to WHERE.   The way you have this written, the " t1.id = '8675309'" is only being applied to the last left join

Comment: face palm....thx,

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 t1.*
,t2.*
,t3.*
FROM
    test1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN test3 t3 ON t3.id = t1.id
    where
        t1.id = '8675309'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `where` clause, not an `on` clause.  When the `from` clause only has `left join`s, the conditions on the first table should be in the `where` clause.  The conditions on all other tables should be in the `on` clause.

This might sound arcane, but there is a simple rule:  a `left join` keeps all rows in the first table even when the `on` clause evaluates to false.  So, conditions on the first table do not matter.

You want:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM test1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     test2 t2
     ON t2.id = t1.id LEFT JOIn
     t3
     ON t3.id = t1.id
WHERE t1.id = 8675309;
```

I should also note that you oversimplified your query, so it is basically equivalent to:

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM test1 t1
WHERE t1.id = 8675309;
```

I assume that this is not your intention.